# Can downstepped verbs in て-form become Heiban?

Tags: て-form, pitch-accent, compound-verbs

- **Example #1:** At [5m28s](https://youtu.be/Y-yhT7ScHIg?t=328), it sounds like 出てきました is being pronounced as deTEKIMAshita, even though it "should be" pronounced as DEtekiMAshita
- **Example #2:** Similarly, at [2m37s](https://youtu.be/o2ZvYn9emeM?t=157), it sounds like 見て描いたり is being pronounced as miTEKAitari, even though it "should be" pronounced as MIteKAitari.

**Questions:**

1. Am I totally mishearing these examples? Or are downstepped verbs switching to a Heiban pronunciation in these て-forms?
2. Assuming I'm not mishearing: are there any general rules as to when downstepped verbs in て-form switch to Heiban like this?

My best guess is that this happens with 2-mora downstepped verbs (since here both 出る and 見る are 2-mora verbs)?

Comment: The rise on て (and also り) in #2 is due to her 語尾上げ intonation, not regional accent.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but may be of interest to you https://accent.u-biq.org/doushi3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated based on aguijonazo's comment above)

The two examples can be explained differently.

見て描いたり - this is two verbs describing two consecutive actions. 語尾上げ is happenning towards the ends of the first and the second. It doesn't have to happen in both places, though. In fact, I would say it's more common to raise the second one only.

出てきました - this is one compound verb describing one action. 語尾上げ doesn't usually happen in the middle of a verb, even if it's compound. With that possibility eliminated, here the speaker's regional accent might be slightly affecting the speech spoken mostly in the Tokyo accent. It's not a very large deviation, and something that can go unnoticed easily.

From the linked pages:

> a native Japanese speaker living in Fukuoka, Japan